# How do I upgrade TCL on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I updated the PORTS tree and run portmaster -a, but came to a screeching halt at:

```
===>>> The lang/tcl-modules port has been deleted: Modules are now part of the base Tcl distributions
===>>> Aborting update
```

So, I installed TCL86 manually and tried to remove tcl-modules, but I'm stuck here now:

```
/ # pkg_delete lang/tcl-modules
pkg_delete: no such package 'tcl-modules' installed
```

What's the right way to handle this conflict so I can continue upgrading all my other ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove manually this `tcl-modules` package, but `pkg_delete` is asking for a complete package name (with version).

To remove your old `tcl-modules` package, first get its complete package name:

```
$ pkg_info -aI |grep tcl-modules
tcl-modules-8.6.x  Tcl common modules
```

Then remove it:

```
$ pkg_delete tcl-modules-8.6.x
```

Comment: Cool, it looks like this *should* work.  Unfortunately I'm still getting errors, but I believe it's just due to me being trapped in FreeBSD ports dependency hell where everything seems to depend on old versions of everything else...  :-)

Comment: Yep. But that's true for almost every system. Sometimes, you had to remove "everything" to properly upgrade ;)

Comment: Note: With pkgng (the new standard), remove the '_' and replace with a space in the above commands...